# Using an interpolating solution of NDSolve into an algebraic expression

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

I would like to use the interpolating solution of NDSolve into an algebraic expression without creating a system of a differential equation and algebraic equation.

The example is the following, the differential eq. is

```
NDSolve[{
  x'[t] == -Sqrt[(1/(4 - 2 Sqrt[2]) + (4 - 2 Sqrt[2])/(2 x[t]))^2 - 1],
  x[0] == 4}, 
  x, {t, 0, 10}]
```

The algebraic expression is

```
m[t] Sqrt[1 + x'[t]^2] - m[t]^2/(2 x[t]) + 1 == 0
```

that I need to solve for `m[t]`

Answer (score 2):

You have your `NDSolve`

```
xsoln = NDSolve[{x'[
     t] == -Sqrt[(1/(4 - 2 Sqrt[2]) + (4 - 2 Sqrt[2])/(2 x[t]))^2 - 
       1], x[0] == 4}, x, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

which returns a replacement rule.  This replacement rule will work with derivatives, just try `Plot[{x[t], x'[t]} /. xsoln, {t, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True]` to see this.

Then you solve the algebraic equation and act upon it with this replacement rule, generating a new set of replacement rules

```
msoln = Solve[m[t] Sqrt[1 + x'[t]^2] - m[t]^2/(2 x[t]) + 1 == 0, 
   m[t]] /. First@xsoln
```

[image]

You can plot the two solutions using this replacement rule,

```
Plot[m[t] /. msoln, {t, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

#### Initialization

One alternative is to construct new interpolating functions from the solutions.

```
dsol = x /. 
   First@NDSolve[{x'[
        t] == -Sqrt[(1/(4 - 2 Sqrt[2]) + (4 - 
                2 Sqrt[2])/(2 x[t]))^2 - 1], x[0] == 4}, 
     x, {t, 0, 10}];

msol = Solve[m[t] Sqrt[1 + x'[t]^2] - m[t]^2/(2 x[t]) + 1 == 0, m[t]]
(*
  {{m[t] -> x[t] Sqrt[1 + Derivative[1][x][t]^2] - 
      Sqrt[x[t]] Sqrt[2 + x[t] + x[t] Derivative[1][x][t]^2]},
   {m[t] ->  x[t] Sqrt[1 + Derivative[1][x][t]^2] + 
      Sqrt[x[t]] Sqrt[2 + x[t] + x[t] Derivative[1][x][t]^2]}}
*)
```

#### Solution

See below for discussion.

```
removearg = h_[t] :> h;
vals = {
   x -> dsol["ValuesOnGrid"],
   x' -> dsol'["ValuesOnGrid"],
   x'' -> NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], 
     Flatten@dsol["Grid"], dsol["ValuesOnGrid"], "DifferenceOrder" -> 2]};

mfns = MapThread[
   Interpolation@Transpose@{dsol["Grid"], ##} &,
   {m[t] /. msol /. removearg /. vals,
    D[m[t] /. msol, t] /. removearg /. vals}
   ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[Through[mfns[t]], {t, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Discussion

To get an order-3 Hermite interpolation, like the one produced by `NDSolve`, we need to supply the function and derivative values of `m` on an interpolation grid. Here is a fake example just to let you inspect the pieces of the computation without being overwhelmed by the volume of data in `dsol`.

```
MapThread[
 Transpose@{List /@ Range[3], ##} &,
 {m[t] /. msol /. h_[t] :> h /. {
    x -> Range[3]^3,
    x' -> 3. Range[3]^2},
  D[m[t] /. msol, t] /. h_[t] :> h /. {
    x -> Range[3]^3,
    x' -> 3. Range[3]^2,
    x'' -> 6. Range[3]}}
 ]
(*
  {{{{1}, -0.301824, 0.456501}, {{2}, -0.0830097, 0.0823127}, {{3}, -0.0370107, 0.0246378}},
   {{{1}, 6.62638, 29.9014}, {{2}, 192.749, 480.253}, {{3}, 1459.04, 2430.31}}}
*)
```

Since `m[t]` contains `x'[t]`, then `m'[t]` will contain `x''[t]`.  There are a couple of problems with `x''[t]`.  In cubic Hermite interpolation, the second derivative is not guaranteed to be continuous.  The discontinuities will be on the interpolation grid, so estimating `x''[t]` at the grid points involves a choice.  The second problem is that the initial steps taken by `NDSolve` are usually quite small.  The purpose seems to be to take small steps while enough steps are accumulated so that the finite difference derivatives are reasonably accurate and the error estimate can be trusted.  One can see that the second derivative oscillates a bit wildly at the beginning. It over a very small interval, so its importance depends on the importance of the behavior of `m[t]` for `t` near `0`.  (See Fig. 1.)

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>   Fig. 1. *A plot of `x''[t]` showing the oscillation and discontinuities near `t == 0`.  The range of the oscillations is in fact larger than `0.3`, or about 1000 times as great as shown.*
>
> ```
> Plot[dsol''[t], {t, 0, 1/2}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
> ```

We can use [`` NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html#1106740037) to estimate `x''[t]` as seen in the code for `vals`.  Since `NDSolve` computes and stores `x'[t]` in the solution, these values on the grid points may be assumed to be accurate.  So we might estimate ``` x''[t]`` from either ```dsol[t]`or`dsol'[t]`.  Each way is roughly equivalent and better than using`dsol''[t]`.  I chose using`dsol[t]` above.

> [image: Mathematica graphics]
>   Fig. 2. *Estimates of `x''[t]`: `dsol''[t]` (blue), the (finite difference) first derivative of `dsol'[t]` (yellow), and the (finite difference) second derivative of `dsol[t]` (green).*
>
> ```
> ListLinePlot[
>  {dsol''["ValuesOnGrid"],
>   NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], 
>    Flatten@dsol["Grid"], dsol'["ValuesOnGrid"], 
>    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2],
>   NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], 
>    Flatten@dsol["Grid"], dsol["ValuesOnGrid"], 
>    "DifferenceOrder" -> 2]},
>  PlotRange -> All]
> ```

As a final note, the rule `removearg = h_[t] :> h` used in the code converts `m[t]` to `m`, `x[t]` to `x`, `x'[t]` to `x'` and so forth.